# Best way for user management with Hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am currently trying to move our Puppet setup to further use Hiera. In regard to this, I would like to create the users with Hiera, but having some problems how to do this when moving up in the hierarchy.

The scenario is that I want to have a set of base users which are included in every installation. Also, I sometimes need to add some specific users only for a different subset of nodes, maybe specific to some datacenters or to some nodes.

So I thought about the following setup:

hiera.yaml:

```
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "datacenter/${::datacenter}"
  - "common"
```

users.pp:

```
class profile::users {
  $user_accounts = hiera('user_accounts')
  create_resources(user, $user_accounts)
}
```

and in common.yaml:

```
user_accounts:
  bob:
    comment: "Bob"
    managehome: true
```

and then go up the hierarchy.
The main problems I see with this is:

- How do I implement default attributes for each user? For example, in this example, I want to set `managehome: true` for *all* users, and not explicitly write it every time. I maybe want to disable it sometimes, though.
- If I have `user_accounts` further up in the hierarchy, it would overwrite the `user_accounts` hash from common.yaml, so that I would need to duplicate the entries. I stumbled across the [deep merging](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/lookup_types.html#deep-merging-in-hiera) in Hiera, but wonder if this is actually used or is best practice. Also, it would not solve the first problem, and I need to set `merge_behavior` in hiera.yaml, which I want to avoid.
- How could I insert ssh keys for every user here? The nicest solution would be to just add the ssh keys as an attribute to the user account.

So, does anyone have an insight how user management is actually nicely done with Puppet? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement default attributes for each user in the type definition:

```
define user($managehome = true) { ... }
```

Yes, you need to use merging, but rather than specifying it in the hiera data, use the [`hiera_array` function](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#hieraarray) to do the lookup for the data you want.

SSH keys are just another attribute in the data set, which your `user` type should set appropriately on the system.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think this worked. Instead of the create_resource() function I have found under https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/lang_resources_advanced.html#implementing-the-createresources-function that this is easier done with an iteration, so I just put the defaults in there. I'll further try this, but in a quick smoke test it worked.